# How to access, read, and analyse 1000s of textfile using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, text

I need to make a desktop app that  takes about 1000 or so textfiles (each file contains about 10 or so columns with company audit info), go into them, and search for irregularities and then display those irregularities to the user of the app.

By irregularities I mean any data in the files that is not consistent with the other fields of data.

Anyways, my main concern is that I don't know how to access all those text files using VB.net.
I mean I know how to read/input into files but how do I actually access 1000s of files from a folder and then search through them. Is this where query languages such as SQL come in? Should I just make an object/pointer ?

Thanks

Comment: Use the [Directory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) to get a list of files in the folder.

Comment: ^- And if possible (I don't know your specs), process the files parallel (consider this if you have many files and the performance is not as expected).